# Missing developer SDK's on Mac 10.8.2

Tags: xcode, macos, sdk

I recently upgraded from 10.6.8 to 10.8.2.  I need to compile software that uses the 10.7 SDK.  However, whenever I go into `/Developer/SDKs/` all I see are: MacOSX10.4u.sdk, MacOSX10.5.sdk, and MacOSX10.6.sdk.  I'm hoping I'd have at least MacOSX10.7.sdk, but it's non-existent.  I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I'm using Xcode 4.6.

Anyone know how to get the newer SDK's or at least explain why mine are missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In more recent versions of Xcode they're inside the app bundle:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
```

Answer (score 0):

you upgraded the os, but not the xcode. so those are your initial sdks.

i would also like to know where to get the sdk only. xcode 4.+ sucks memory and crashes a lot.